# Ao salvar uma imagem no S3 usando a função Lambda da AWS com PHP, o arquivo é salvo como .bin

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-aws

Tenho uma aplicação Laravel que roda como função Lambda na AWS. Quando faço o upload de uma imagem, usando o driver S3, o arquivo final é salvo com a extensão *.bin*.

Utilizei o método *storeAs*, para definir o nome do arquivo e manter a extensão original, mas quando abro, o arquivo parece estar corrompido.

O trecho do código atualmente é este.

```
$file = $request->file('image');
$filename = 'anuncio.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$file->storeAs('img/anuncios', $filename);
```

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: porque que ao inves de usar o metodo `... $file->getClientOriginalExtension()` voce nao separa o  nome inteiro do arquivo usando split, algo tipo `filename.split('/').pop().split('.')[1]`
tenta ai, se nao resolver avisa, se resolver, vota no meu comentario

Comment: Esse método traz a extensão do arquivo corretamente. O problema é que  quando pego esse arquivo lá no S3, a imagem não abre. Eu usei uma ferramenta que gera um hash do arquivo. Comparei e, o arquivo original é realmente diferente do que vai pro S3.

Comment: acho que isso vai te ajudar https://medium.com/@ediltondanniken/salvando-seus-arquivos-no-amazon-s3-com-laravel-f20d389c6185

Comment: Ja tinha tentado. Quando faço dessa forma,  é quando o arquivo vai para o S3 com a extensão .bin

Comment: cara, teria de ver mais do seu codigo para ter uma ideia do porque estar salvando errado

Comment: Isso começou a acontecer depois que coloquei ele no Lambda da AWS. Antes disso tava funcionando normalmente